# Best practice for adding a conflicting package with Poetry

Tags: python, python-poetry, tox

I have a project which uses `awscli` - the version I  have installed is `1.29.29`

I want to add `tox` so I ran `poetry add tox -G dev` and it failed

```
Because no versions of awscli match >1.29.29,<1.29.30 || >1.29.30,<1.29.31 || >1.29.31,<1.29.32 || >1.29.32,<2.0.0
 and awscli (1.29.30) depends on colorama (>=0.2.5,<0.4.5), awscli (>1.29.29,<1.29.31 || >1.29.31,<1.29.32 || >1.29.32,<2.0.0) requires colorama (>=0.2.5,<0.4.5).
And because awscli (1.29.31) depends on colorama (>=0.2.5,<0.4.5), awscli (>1.29.29,<1.29.32 || >1.29.32,<2.0.0) requires colorama (>=0.2.5,<0.4.5).
And because awscli (1.29.32) depends on colorama (>=0.2.5,<0.4.5)
 and awscli (1.29.29) depends on colorama (>=0.2.5,<0.4.5), awscli (>=1.29.29,<2.0.0) requires colorama (>=0.2.5,<0.4.5).
Because no versions of tox match >4.10.0,<5.0.0
 and tox (4.10.0) depends on colorama (>=0.4.6), tox (>=4.10.0,<5.0.0) requires colorama (>=0.4.6).
Thus, tox (>=4.10.0,<5.0.0) is incompatible with awscli (>=1.29.29,<2.0.0).
So, because warpspeed-multiclass-model depends on both tox (^4.10.0) and awscli (^1.29.29), version solving failed.
```

Not providing a version for tox seems to have been interpreted as `>4.10.0,<5.0.0` - is that correct?

What is the best practice - I ran `poetry add "tox<=4.10.0" -G dev` and it found a solution (tox==3.28.0) but is there a way of solving "I need tox `>4.10.0,<5.0.0` and you can upgrade/downgrade other packages (specifically `awscli`, `sagemaker` and `boto3` from the `sagemaker` group) to suit?

Answer (score 3):

I would not add tox via poetry at all, as tox is a generic test command line tool.

That means, I strongly prefer to install tox outside of a project, preferable via [pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/).

Then you can use tox to run poetry, either an already installed poetry, or tox installs poetry (inside a virtual environment) and then runs it.

This is also described in poetry's official documentation.

- [tox runs already installed poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/faq/#usecase-2)
- [tox installs and runs poetry](https://python-poetry.org/docs/faq/#usecase-3)

Disclaimer: I am one of the maintainers of tox.

Comment: Generally, `tox` is useful if you want to run your tests across multiple Python versions. But for this there are other solutions as well, like native Python version matrixes on Github Actions.